# Removable Storage Access in Android with NDK API

Tags: android, android-ndk, storage, external, sd-card

My question should be kinda simple but I search a lot from the internet, cannot find the answer.

I could get the path of secondary removable storage(sdcard) with below code

```
String ExternalSdcardPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") + "/Sample/";
```

and I could get path like this , /storage/external_SD/Sample/

and I tried to create file with NDK API ( fopen(ExternalSdcardPath, "a+"); )

but I couldn't create and read file with fopen..

can you please tell me how to create and read file with fopen api in removable path(secondary_storage) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could get the path of secondary removable storage(sdcard) with below code

There is no requirement for that environment variable to exist, let alone point to something meaningful.

> I couldn't create and read file with fopen

You do not have direct filesystem access to arbitrary locations on removable storage on Android 4.4+.

> can you please tell me how to create and read file with fopen api in removable path(secondary_storage) ?

Your only places for direct filesystem access to removable storage is in the locations returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and `getExternalMediaDirs()`. Those are all methods on `Context` (e.g., an activity or service). If they return 2+ values, the second and subsequent ones are on removable storage. Your Java code can supply those paths to your NDK code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I tested what you said and could get removable path ( File[] files = getExternalFilesDirs("");  and string path = files[1].getAbsolutePath() ,  sdcard/Android/data/my package folder) and create file in removable storage pacakge folder with my NDK code.
Should I get access and write and read permission to other path , sdcard/test_folder ( not package folder ) ??

Comment: @Ji.Hoon.Kim: As I wrote in my answer, you do not have direct filesystem access to arbitrary locations on removable storage (e.g., whatever `sdcard/test_folder` is supposed to be) on Android 4.4+.

Comment: I've got direct filesystem access to arbitrary locations on removable storage with SAF ( DocumentFile API , Android 5.0.1+ , Lollipop ).  Can I use SAF without SAF Google UI on Android 5.0.1+ ?

Comment: @Ji.Hoon.Kim: The `DocumentFile` API is not "direct filesystem access", as I used the phrase. "Can I use SAF without SAF Google UI on Android 5.0.1+ ?" -- no. The point behind the SAF is to allow the *user* to provide access rights in a fine-grained fashion, and that requires a UI for the user to grant those rights.